# How can i auto rotate this carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

How can I auto rotate this carousel?

I am following [this carousel tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJcdp.png) but I don't know how to auto rotate it.

**jQuery:**

```
var items,length,deg,z,move = 0;

function rotate(direction)
{
    move += direction;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        items[i].style.transform = "rotateY("+(deg*(i+move))+"deg) translateZ("+z+"px)";
    }
}

function load()
{
    items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    length = items.length;

    deg = 360 / length;
    z = (items[0].offsetWidth / 2) / Math.tan((deg / 2) * (Math.PI / 180));

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        items[i].style.transform = "rotateY("+(deg*i)+"deg) translateZ("+z+"px)";
    }
}

  window.addEventListener('load', load);
```

**css:**

```
*
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html ,body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
.carousel
{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

    perspective:1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.carousel .item
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;

    border: 1px solid black;

    transition:transform 1s;
}
```

**html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Practice</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="item"><img src="image/logo.jpg" style="height:199px; width:398px;"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="image/slide1.jpg" style="height:199px; width:398px;"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="image/slide2.jpg" style="height:199px; width:398px;"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="image/slide3.jpg" style="height:199px; width:398px;"></div>
        </div>

        <button onclick="rotate(1)">Rotate</button>
        <script src="carousel.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SetInterval`

```
setInterval(function(){ rotate(1); }, 3000);
```

[Set Interval manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

if you make your js file like this, it should auto rotate and also if you click the button, the carousel will rotate too.

```
var items,length,deg,z,move = 0;

function rotate(direction)
{
    move += direction;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        items[i].style.transform = "rotateY("+(deg*(i+move))+"deg) translateZ("+z+"px)";
    }
}

function load()
{
    items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    length = items.length;

    deg = 360 / length;
    z = (items[0].offsetWidth / 2) / Math.tan((deg / 2) * (Math.PI / 180));

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        items[i].style.transform = "rotateY("+(deg*i)+"deg) translateZ("+z+"px)";
    }

    setInterval(function(){ rotate(1); }, 10000); //auto rotate every 10 seconds(10,000 miliseconds)
}

window.addEventListener('load', load);
```

Comment: why the rotate is getting faster and i want auto rotate w/out using the button

Comment: You can change the interval from 3000 to 10000 (it's in milliseconds)
Yes, you don't need to use the button, just put that code at the end of your load function

Comment: hi sir can i ask how can i add a previous rotate in a button than for this auto rotate sir its so awesome :D